# JS Can't use array initialized within for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding how scoping works in JS, my background is in R and Python.

This is a toy example. The games_array always prints out as empty at the end. And the array variable doesn't seem to be present in the console.

```
    for(var row_i = 0; row_i < 50; row_i++){

        var games_array = [];

        if(row_i % 2 == 0){

            console.log(data[row_i].name);
            games_array.push(data[row_i].name);
        }
    }
    console.log(games_array);
```

But then this works:

```
    var games_array = [];

    for(var row_i = 0; row_i < 50; row_i++){

        if(row_i % 2 == 0){

            console.log(data[row_i].name);
            games_array.push(data[row_i].name);
        }
    }
    console.log(games_array);
```

I don't understand why I can't create an empty array and use it within a for loop.
I need to wrap this inside an outer loop and use the games_array in the outerloop.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you only want to process the even rows, why don't you do `row_i += 2` instead of checking whether it's even each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with scoping. After all, since you declared the variable using `var` instead of `let`, the scope extends outside of the for loop. The problem is that each time the loop runs, it sets `games_array` to `[]`, which means the array gets cleared each time the loop runs.

In the second example, you only initialize the array once, which is why it works.